# How can make gridview align on top of table cell

Tags: html, css, html-table

If the records on "gv1" is less than the "gv2" (on the image), "gv1" is
aligned center and keeps jumpy when tick the checkBox, I want the
gridview are always on top of table cell.

How can I write CSS that the gridview is set on top of the table cell?

```
    <style type="text/css">                    
        .top
        {
          vertical-align:top;
         }
        </style>

           <table border="2" style="width: 1050px">
            <tr>
             <td class="style9">Building </td>
             <td class="style10" colspan="2">dropdownlist </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
             <td >Unit</td>
             <td >
                <div class="top">
                Update Panel &GridView
                </div> 
             </td>
             <td >
                <div class="top">
                Update Panel &GridView
                </div>
            </td>
            </tr>           
            </table>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `vertical-align:top` for table cell or try

```
td{
vertical-align:text-top;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me too - I had been trying 'vertical-align' in the CSS, but was applying it to the gridview control, rather than applying it to the table cell.